# Other than $\models$, is there standardized notation for semantic consequence?

Tags: logic, notation

It is common practice to use $\models$ both for the satisfaction relation between models and sentences, and for the corresponding semantic consequence relation.

**Question.** Suppose I don't want to use $\models$ for semantic consequence (personally, I think this particular convention causes more confusion than its worth), what should I use instead? In particular, is there a standardized alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ben-Gurion University, where I did my B.Sc. and M.Sc. we used $T\implies\varphi$ to denote logical implication, which was really a semantic property:

> $T\implies\varphi$ if and only if for every interpretation for the language $M$ and assignment $s$ for $M$, such that every formula in $T$ is true under that assignment; $\varphi$ is true under $s$ as well.

This makes all the more reason to pay attention as to what is $\implies$ and what is $\rightarrow$ (statement about propositions vs. a connective in the language).

Comment: Thanks. Is this considered standard in Israeli mathematical circles?

Comment: I'm not sure, really. I actually don't know what's the common notation in my current university, The Hebrew University, and to add insult to injury I was the TA (and in five weeks will be again) in the Logic 2 course. :-)