# Difference between implies and "turnstile" symbols (→ and ⊢)

Tags: logic, notation, convention, meta-math

According to [Wikipedia's list of logic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols):

`A → B` means *A → B is false when A is true and B is false but true otherwise.*

`A ⊢ B` means *x ⊢ y means x proves (syntactically entails) y*

But for me I can't see how they aren't equivalent. If a set of theorems/lemmas, **A**, can be used to derive another set of proofs/lemmas, **B**, then doesn't **A** *imply* **B**?

---

Googling around on this topic it seems that ⊢ may just be a "stronger" version of →. I know that we often use → for little steps in logic, and it seems that ⊢ is more used for larger steps.

Then I found this part of an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/640266/539148) in a question about symbol standardisation:

> Now 'A implies B' gets used in informal talk both as variant on 'if A
> then B' and as a variant of 'A logically entails B', i.e. as both what
> we might regiment as → and as ⊢ [or ⊨]. And low and
> behold, we find ⟹ being confusingly used both ways [in the object
> language, or in the metalanguage]. Conservatism in symbolism is a Good
> Thing, so I think the use of ⟹ is to be deprecated: I'd say, use → for
> an object language conditional, and the appropriate ***turnstile in
> metalanguage***.

(Emphasis mine)

So this would imply to me that → and ⊢ are equivalent, but it's idiomatic to use ⊢ for metamathematics, and → otherwise. Or, more concretely:

`(A → B) → (C → D)` is the same as `(A → B) ⊢ (C → D)`, but the second option is considered more idiomatic/readable as we differentiate the smaller connections from the larger ones.

Is this right?

Comment: Well, also, $A\to B$ makes sense in propositional logic, which is not rich enough to talk about "entailment": it's just (as you say), an assertion about the four possible combinations of true or false for $A$ and $B$. Not about "proving" anything... The A-proves-B symbol has more depth to it: there's a _reason/proof_ for the truth of one, given the truth of the other (essentially). Is this vaguely responding to your question?

Comment: @paulgarrett, thank you. I'm just getting into learning logic, and felt I couldn't get started without knowing the difference. I think that the strictness of "→" is lost on me at the moment - but you've helped me know where to look next. Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251001/21813) is *my* understanding/summary; I also like (and upvoted) Peter Smith's answer on the same page. (Caveat: the word "implication" and symbol "⇒" does really have multiple usage agreements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So this would imply to me that → and ⊢ are equivalent,

No, it means they are distinct application of a similar concept in different environments.

- $\to$ is used as a logical connective *in a* statement; the material conditional.
- $\vdash$ is used to indicate syntactic entailment *between sets of* statements; a sequent.$$p\vee r, p\to q ~\vdash~ r\lor q$$

---

The reason the $\implies$ symbol is being depreciated, is because using the same symbol for these purposes is quite confusing.

---

A syntactic entailment means that when given a set of premises, the consequent may be derived using some specified set of axioms and rules of inference.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Apologies for my ignorance, but why couldn't we write `(∨, →) → ∨` ?

Comment: Because that is not a **well-formed formula**.   It also does not clearly convey the intent of "it is provable". @Elliott

Comment: Okay, thanks again. So if I understand you, the difference is that `A → B` is a function that outputs true if A implies B, but false otherwise; but `A ⊢ B` is the written claim that A implies B. Is that right? If so, it seems like the syntax is backwards.

Comment: In terms of it not being a well-formed formula, I thought we could convert `,` to `∧`, so its formal equivalent would be `(( ∨ ) ∧ ( → )) → ( ∨ )`.